# Trouble with MSAL and Python

Tags: python, azure-ad-msal

I set up the app following the guide provided BY MS and download the MSAL python file. It contains the correct client ID and client secret, but even after using localhost:5000. This is what I get. "unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908%22). This is my personal account for testing. Then I tried my work account, got the same thing. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When registering the application, you need to select the "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)" value.

Read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-a-new-application-using-the-azure-portal

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/37847